# Join 3 tables with Inner join or left join and display count

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have 3 tables contacts, Broadcast list, and broadcast_contact. Where Broadcastlist and Contact table is referenced to broadcast_contacts. Every contact is always associated with one or more Broadcast list.

[image]

Where do I want to show the count of contacts that are in the broadcast list.I want to display all broadcast name and count of the contacts in that particular broadcast with join and group by.

Example:-

[image]

Currently I have only two table(broadcast and contact) where broadcast table is referenced in contact table it self. And I am able to fetch count with the two table. Now I want to do the same with three table. because one contact could be in multiple broadcast list.

Comment: If you only need count of `contacts`, you don't need to join table `contacts`, you only need to join `broadcast_contact` and count `broadcast_contact.Contact_id`. For example `select bl.*,count(bc.Contact_id) as contact_count from broadcastlist bl inner join broadcast_contact bc on bc.Broadcast_id = bl.id group by bl.id`

Comment: This is working for me just the basic count with two tables, but I need to join the 3rd table as I want to apply some of the conditions from the contacts table.

Comment: try query like `select bl.*,count(bc.Contact_id) as contact_count from broadcastlist bl inner join broadcast_contact bc on bc.Broadcast_id = bl.id inner join contacts c on c.id = bc.Contact_id where c.FirstName = "foo" group by bl.id` ?

Comment: @Cositanto I have tried the same, but the count is not proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below query to get the desired output.

```
SELECT bcl.BroadcastName AS "Broadcast List Name", 
        (SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) 
        FROM broadcast_contact bc 
        LEFT JOIN Contacts c ON bc.contact_id = c.id 
        WHERE bc.broadcast_id = bcl.id AND c.FirstName LIKE "%E") AS Recepients 
FROM Broadcastlist bcl;
```